# Heroku serving bad home page on custom domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

What could be causing an app that is hosted on heroku to serve a different home pages?

This renders correctly
http://ninezoom.herokuapp.com/

This does not
http://9zoom.com/

This is fine though
http://9zoom.com/features

Comment: I get a lot of `404` errors for the assets in the `9zoom.com` version...

Comment: Interesting home page using this for css "/assets/application-62ab4be5c62c21950ee1bcb95264ffee.css"  but other pages use "/assets/application-faefd197791fc123cc34917c0af5f643.css"  herokuapp version serves this "/assets/application-faefd197791fc123cc34917c0af5f643.css" so seems to be some sort of cache issue with the home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was memcached.  I forgot to clear cache
Rails.cache.clear